# Add user data to database with firebase (React) (Google authentication)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add user data to Firebase database on Sign-in. The user shows up in Authentication, but there is no data being posted to the actual database.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);


const signIn = () => {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  var promise = firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)

  promise.then( result => {

    var user = result.user;

    firebase.database().ref('users/'+user.uid).set({
      email: user.email,
      name: user.displayName
    })

  }).catch( e => {
    //handle errors

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider) will redirect the page to the OAuth provider and then back to the current page.
To get the result and save the user, you need to call:

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(result => {
   var user = result.user;
   if (user) {
     // Save user.
   }
}).catch(e => {
});
```

Comment: Where should one place the `getRedirectResult()` call? Should it be in the `signIn` property under the `signInWithRedirect()` call?

Comment: Excluding Cordova apps, `getRedirectResult` should be outside `signInWithRedirect`. The latter will redirect the page so you have no ability to get the result when it is called.

Comment: I meant should `getRedirectResult()` be inside the same `signIn()` method, or should it be somewhere else in the component - say, a `componentDidMount()` method?

Comment: It should not be in the `signIn()` method. It is better placed in the `componentDidMount()`. Keep in mind that after a user is signed in and not coming from a redirect operation, `onAuthStateChanged` should be used instead.

Comment: That's actually my point. Just like in your suggestion, I have both - `getRedirectResult()` and `onAuthStateChanged()` - in `componentDidMount()` method. However, both of these auth functions get called every time a component loads. So, if I have logic inside of `getRedirectResult()` that I want to run only once - upon successful authentication - keeping it in `componentDidMount()` would be undesirable?

Comment: Do you need to get the credential from `getRedirectResult`? If not, just use `onAuthStateChanged`. If you need the credential, you can embed `getRedirectResult` inside `onAuthStateChanged` when user is not null.

Comment: You mean `getRedirectResult` is actually optional? Because I get the `user` from `onAuthStateChanged` as well, which is enough in my case.

Comment: `getRedirectResult` provides a way to get additional information you normally can get with `signInWithPopup` such as the type of operation, additional user info, credential, possible errors from the operation, etc. If you don't need that, then `onAuthStateChanged` is sufficient to determine the current auth state. The downside is that if an error occurred in `signInWithRedirect` you won't be able to get that. You could embed `getRedirectResult` when there is no user within `onAuthStateChanged` to just check if an error occurred in the sign-in operation.